# Java finding Zero Points with Newton Algorithm endless loop

Tags: java, algorithm, math, infinite-loop, newtons-method

I'm havinga Problem with a method, which takes a Polynom like f(x)=x²+1 and calculates possible zero points with the newton algorithm.
I have given requirements for specific variables so even if the naming is not good or a variable is not needed I have to use them :/
The Polynom I give my method as a parameter is a double-array: For f(x)=x²+1 it would be `{1.0,0.0,1.0}`
so its constructed like `1.0*x^0 + 0.0*x^1+1.0*x^2`

For my Code:
`x0` is the start value for the newton algorithm and `eps` is for the accuracy of the calculation

I followed my given Instructions and got the following code working:

```
public static double newton(double[] a, double x0, double eps) { 
    double z;
    double xn; 
    double xa = x0; 
    double zaehler;
    double nenner;

    do {
        zaehler = horner(a, xa);
        nenner = horner(ableit(a), xa);
        if(nenner == 0) {
            return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        }
        xn = xa - (zaehler/nenner);
        xa = xn;
    } while((Math.abs(horner(a, xn))) >= eps);
    z = xn;
    return 0;
}
```

the method `horner()` calculates the y-Value of a given function for a given x-Value.

My Problem is if the Function doesn't has a zero-point like `x²+1` and I start with `x0=1` and `eps=0.1` I get Infinity returned.
But If I start with `x0=10` and `eps=0.1`for example I create an endless loop.

How can I deal with this or is this a general Problem with the Newton Algorithm?!
Is the only way to set a fixed maximum of Iterations? 
The Code is working for Polynoms that have at least one zero-point!

Comment: You may count the times of loop, or track the result which expect they are running closer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite Loop : Determining and breaking out of Infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738633/infinite-loop-determining-and-breaking-out-of-infinite-loop)

Comment: The variable names make your code quite difficult for non-German (?) speakers to read.

Comment: Always look at a graph of your function to try and gain some insight into it. I use Wolfram Alpha a lot for this kinds of questions.

Answer (score 2):

The Newton–Raphson method *requires the existence* of a **real** root `x` such that `f(x)=0`. The function you use `x^2+1`  has no real roots, so your algorithm will not work in this case (nor in others where there is no root).

Since `x^2+1 >= 1` for all real `x` this implies `horner(a, xn) >= 1`, so the loop

```
while((Math.abs(horner(a, xn))) >= eps)
```

will not terminate for `eps < 1`.

Maybe before starting to iterate, you should check the existence of a zero. 
E.g. if the highest (according to the power of `x`) nonzero coefficient is odd then there will be a real zero.

Or extend your algorithm such that it previously tries to find some real `a`and `b` such that `f(a)f(b) <= 0` (then between `a` and `b` there is a root).